# Remote connection from cPanel to MySQL on WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am trying to use a simple PHP connection to connect remotely to a MySQL database. I have searched many threads and still receiving error 'Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my IP address' (111 "Connection refused")'

I can access the server remotely using the wan IP address no problem i.e. The software files. I am using port forwarding to do that on port 80.

My connection is very simple

```
<?php
$servername = "my ip address";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have tried the following;

1. Creating a new user with all privileges in phpMyAdmin and using % as host
2. Allow from all in phpmyadmin.conf and HTTP.conf (don't think this is the problem)
3. Adding port forwarding on router to 3306
4. Disabled all firewalls on local machine
5. Adding bind-address = 0.0.0.0 to my.ini file (restarting the server)

A lot of thread suggest that the default bind-address is set to localhost or 127.0.0.1 but in my.ini under [mysqld] all I have from default is

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
port = 3306
```

I am using WAMP version 3.1.9 64 bit version

Comment: Have you tried a different client? I see you mentioned phpMyAdmin, can you use that to connect remotely? How about from CLI?

Comment: Assuming that your WAN IP is 111.111.111.111 what values are you using in mysqli to open the connection? Do you use domain name? Do you include port?

Comment: Did you restart `mysqld` after the changes in the INI?

Comment: @Dharman yes I can connect to phpMyAdmin from a remote machine using the wan ip address. Can you give any further info on opening the connection?

Comment: @stickybit yes I am restarting all services every time I edit the INI

Comment: Then you should use the exact same connection details as phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your concerns.

First, verify that another machine on your local network can access the database directly at the 3306 port. This will verify that the server is working, that the log in is correct, and that the permissions are correct, and that any firewall settings have been addressed.

After all is working correctly, deal with accessing it via WAN. It's unclear if you're attempting to do this "from inside the house", ie, using your own external WAN ip address from yourself, there are multiple ways this can fail. It *can* work, but that's additional setting/debugging. So ensure you're dealing with a machine that's actually outside your network for this section of the testing.

As it stands, somewhat impossible to know where the trouble lies.

Comment: Hi @Anders8 I can access the phpmyadmin and login from a remote connection and have tested the port. When I test the connection using the php code above stored on the local machine (using wan ip as host) the connection works fine. However when I put the code on a remote server and access the page on local or remote device I still get the same error. I am assuming it has to be a configuration setting in Wamp.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin access means nothing here. You're redirecting WAN port 80 to localmachine port 80, and that's fine, but that means you're actually accessing the DB from the machine serving you the page... which is localmachine. It doesn't address port 3306 from external/WAN to localmachine 3306. When you say "and login from a remote connection" there isn't sufficient specificity to know what you're doing here: log in to PhpMyAdmin? Log in to RDP? Tested which port? 80? 3386?

Comment: Hi @Anders8 yes I meant log in to the PhpMyAdmin on my local machine from a remote machine, but I can see now that would only test port 80. I have run a test at https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ using my wan ip and port 3306 and it is showing the port as open. I can only imagine the problem is that the mysql server is not listening on the ip address. I have tried adding bind-address = 0.0.0.0 just below [mysqld] in my.ini and restarting all services.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I set up another WAMP installation on a separate machine and connected to a separate network. I could get it to connect to the remote MYSQL on my original machine. It appears that the PHP script was blocked by cPanel before the request was even sent. The link here https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/how-to-configure-your-firewall-for-cpanel-services/84/ shows that cPanel does not allow outbound connection on port 3306. Unfortunately I can't access settings on my shared hosting to change this.

Comment: You may be able to get an outbound port in a higher range, like port 20,000. Then on your own router, you could port forward 20,000 to your localmachine 3306.